# How to scroll image like a instagram post?

Tags: swift, xcode, instagram, instagram-api

Maybe this question has already been asked, but I haven't found an answer for swift. 
How to scroll image like a instagram post? 
What need use? 
ScrollView into a tableView or collectionView into a tableView?
Or 
something different?

[Instagram post image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zu7CS.jpg)

Thanks for help.

Comment: I would use collectionView for posts and scrollView with pageController for images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using `collectionView` or possibly `tableView` for posts and inside post with more images I would use `scrollView` (paging enabled) with `pageControl`